# How to enable fabric-ca server to add attributes in certificates

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the Fabric-ca-server-config.yaml, i see following comment in registry section

```
2) once authenticated, **retrieves the identity's attribute names and
#     values which the fabric-ca-server optionally puts into TCerts
#     which it issues for transacting on the Hyperledger Fabric blockchain**.
#     These attributes are useful for making access control decisions in
#     chaincode.
```

My question is how to make it compulsory for ca sever to add these attribute to Tcerts?
For the default setting roles and attributes are not included in the generated certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the fabric-ca-server supports putting attributes in tcerts (transaction certificates), the clients including SDKs do not yet support using tcerts.  They currently always use ecerts (enrollment certificates).  There is a jira item which would allow putting attributes into ecerts also.  See https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3752.  You can track the progress and make any additional requests via jira.